# convert SQL query to Linq

Tags: c#, linq, postgresql

Could somebody assist me in converting a sql query into LINQ ? I well understand SQL queries, but I am a novice in Linq. Thank you so much for help me.

```
SELECT
    subConsulta."NitIps",
    subConsulta."NumFactura",
    COUNT(*) 
FROM
      (SELECT
            DISTINCT acf."NitIps",
            acf."NumFactura",
            acf."TipoSoporte" 
        FROM
                    "t_ArchivoCentralFacturacion" AS acf
        inner join  "t_TRCompartaTiposDocumentalesAC" AS ctd 
                on
                    acf."TipoSoporte"= ctd."Id"
       GROUP BY
            acf."NitIps",
            acf."NumFactura",
            acf."TipoSoporte")as subConsulta 
        GROUP BY
            subConsulta."NitIps",
            subConsulta."NumFactura" 
        ORDER BY
            subConsulta."NitIps",
            subConsulta."NumFactura"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you map your tables to entities it looks like follow:

```
var first = from archivoCentralFacturacion in ArchivoCentralFacturacions
            group archivoCentralFacturacion by new {
              c.NitIps,
              c.NumFactura,
              c.TipoSoporte
            } into subConsulta
            select subConsulta;
var result = (from f in first
              group f by new {
                f.NitIps,
                f.NumFactura
              } into r
              select new {
                NitIps = r.NitIps,
                NumFactura = r.NumFactura,
                ResultCount = r.Count()
              }).OrderBy(x => x.NitIps).ThenBy(x => x.NumFactura);
```